# Is it possible to have constant function parameters in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, constants, oracle19c

Is it possible to have constant function parameters in SQL to make sure the values are not changed later?

Something like this doesn't work:

```sql
function my_func(
        first_param  constant varchar2
      , second_param constant varchar2
      ) return varchar2
   is
... -- Rest
```

Comment: Do you mean so the same value is always passed in - in which case why have it as an argument at all? Or so that any value can be passed by a caller and the function body can't modify it - which is how IN arguments work anyway? [You'll get PLS-00363](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=138ec3ff6e976152a63f443ff1b2bd18) if you try to assign a value to an IN. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not necessary as you cannot redefine an `IN` parameter. For example:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION does_not_work(
  a IN NUMBER,
  b IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  IF a < 2 THEN
    a := 2;
  END IF;
  RETURN GREATEST( a, b );
END;
/
```

*(Note: the `IN` keyword is optional and the default parameter direction; you would get the same error if you declared the signature without the `IN` keywords.)*

Gives:

> ```
> ORA-24344: success with compilation error
> ```

If you look at the errors:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | DOES_NOT_WORK | FUNCTION | 1 | 8 | 5 | PLS-00363: expression 'A' cannot be used as an assignment target | ERROR | 363 |
> | DOES_NOT_WORK | FUNCTION | 2 | 8 | 5 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |

This tells you that you can't use an `IN` parameter as an assignment target.